# auto resize textfield when textfield is editing

Tags: macos

I have problem with my project on Mac OS. I have a textfield, I want to change size it automatically when textfield is editing!Please suggest me a way to solve this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an object as the delegate of your `NSTextField`. As `NSTextField` is a subclass of `NSControl`, it will call the `-controlTextDidChange:` method on your object if you implement it.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField* textField;
}
@end

@implementation MyObject
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [textField setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if([notification object] == textField)
    {
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14];

    }
}
@end
```